# How to add a citation with hyperlink inside a pdf figure (cross referencing from figure to bibliography)?

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, includegraphics, hyperlink, pax

I want to add a citation inside a pdf figure, and would like the citation to be a link to the bibliography.

I know embedding a pdf with `includegraphics` normally mangles the link, but I have found a solution (in pdflatex), using the `pax` package. But am open to any other solution.

`pax` preserves the hyperlink, and I tested it is working with a www address. But for the
internal link to bibliography, I am not sure what link address should I use. At the moment, I insert this link in the pdf figure

"cite.citation_key"

But the result is that the hyperlink points to `/home/user/cite.citation_key` instead of the bibliography. Does anyone know how to achieve this.

Comment: You should add a small but complete example that can be used for tests. An alternative to pax is newpax, which doesn't require an external java call.